# Forcing a file to download via JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a textarea that accepts a bunch of data.  I then submit it via $.ajax to a PHP script that processes it and generates a KML.

```
var pData = $("textarea#data").serialize();
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "tools.php?mode=process",
    data: pData,
    success: function(data)
    {
        window.location.href = "tools.php?mode=download&"+pData;
    });
});
```

This did work fine, until I started getting more and more data.  Now I get a URI Too Large error, and am trying to find an alternative to force a file download.  I tried using $.post() as well, but I can't force it to download.

Comment: Why are you sending all the data to your script, and then again through the URL? Does `process` not save the data somehow?

Comment: What exactly are you passing via `pData` and why do you use two separate calls to pass the same data, one via POST and one via querystring?.. It seems the processing could be done in the same call as the download is initiated.

Comment: @Pekka I'm not really sure.. my brain's not working.  But you bring up a good point, and give me a solid idea on how to fix this.

@Quintin It's a serialized string of a bunch of random bits of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up the discussion in the comments, the optimal workflow for this might be

1. data gets sent to `mode=process` through Ajax and `POST`;
2. script saves result in a temporary file (with a random name) and returns the name of that file in the AJAX response body
3. `location.href` call goes to `mode=download` and the name of the temporary file
4. script opens temporary file, passes it through and deletes it

Answer (score 3):

The best way I found to save data to a file and then force download it with jQuery, create your file and save the data with PHP:

```
       $data = ''; // data passed to a function or via $_POST['data']
       $targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/location/of/file/'; 
       $savedFile = $targetFolder . md5($data). '.html';
       $handle = fopen($savedFile, 'w') or die('Cannot open file: '.$savedFile);
       fwrite($handle, $data); 

       if(file_exists($savedFile)) {
            $fileName = basename($savedFile);
            $fileSize = filesize($savedFile);

            // Output headers.
            header("Cache-Control: private");
            header("Content-Type: application/stream");
            header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);

            // Output file.
            readfile ($savedFile);                   
            exit();
        }
        else {
            die('The provided file path: ' . $savedFile .' is not valid.');
        }
```

Use jquery on a .click function or $.post

```
var forceDownload_URL = 'your/download/function/url.php';

$('#download').click(function(){
     window.open(forceDownload_URL);
});

// Post method untested, but writing on the fly when called as above works well
// getting your forceDownload php to return the absolute path to your file
$.post(forceDownload_URL,{postdata:my_data},function(data){
    window.open(data);
});
```