# saving dataURL image locally via php

Tags: javascript, php, download, html5-canvas

I'm making a PNG image file from a dataURL string (thanks to the example from [The PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)). I'd like this code to open the "Download file" dialog in the browser, so users can save this image locally, but calling the function `imagepng()` saves the image to my server instead. Am I using the wrong function when calling `imagepng()`? I'm trying to trigger a download by changing the headers, but it's still saving to the server.

```
<?php
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
    . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
    . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
    . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

$data = base64_decode($data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);

// set the headers, to trigger a download
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.png"');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im, 'test_2.png');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Also, I'm calling the PHP via the following JavaScript, (not sure if this is relevant to the results I'm getting)

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "php/downloadimg.php",
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
        data : finishedImage.src
    }
})
```

Comment: just call the ``imagepng`` function without the second parameter

Answer (score 1):

just call the `imagepng` function without the second parameter. if you follow the `imagepng` documentation you read that filling in the second parameter the image is saved to this filename.

pass only the image resource to the function and the raw image are send to the client.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagepng.php

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.png"');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

if you use php only files don't use the php close tag `?>` to avoid leaked whitespaces and messed up your output stream.

Comment: Great! Removing the second parameter saves the file locally! However, this only works when I call the PHP with this JS: `window.open("php/downloadimg.php");` I'm trying to pass the `$data` variable to my PHP, so when I call it via
`$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "php/downloadimg.php",...});`
No download happens, even though `$.ajax.done()` is called successfully. Any idea why?

Comment: don't send ajax. replace the hole ajax function with ``window.location='php/downloadimg.php';`` this works fine if do not need to send any other information to the download script.

Comment: But if I use document.location I wouldn't be able to pass variables to my PHP, correct? I need to pass the `$data` variable so that the image that's being saved isn't always the same. I tried passing variables through the URL, like `'php/downloadimg.php?data=pdjejalkjaoseru/3jd...` and it truncates the value because it's too long.

Comment: dont mix your logic, javascript should not be responsable to send the image data wich are then returned by the php script - just to force the download. i think for this you should look at these question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683233/forcing-a-file-to-download-via-jquery

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I thought it would be possible to pass the image data to PHP, and then have PHP save it to the client-side. It looks like I'm going to have to change the way I'm approaching the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that since you've already got the image data in PHP, there's no need to call the `imagepng` function or anything like it.  All you need to do is dump your image data to the client after you set the headers, which will then decide for itself what to do with it.

So, something like this will work if you don't need to actually process the image server side:

```
<?php
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
    . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
    . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
    . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

$data = base64_decode($data);

// set the headers, to trigger a download
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.png"');
header('Content-Type: image/png');

echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: This also works via `window.open("downloadimg.php")` but would this work via `$.ajax({type: "POST",url: "php/downloadimg2.php"})`? The thing is that I need to pass the `$data` variable into the PHP because the image won't always be the same.